# Is there a way to use a range-based iterator to iterate over references to the values of a list of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, iterator, auto

So if I have the following vector with several pointers to ints in it:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> list;
```

Can I later iterate over it using something like:

```
for (auto & (*item) : list)
{
    item.member = something;   //Goal is to require no dereferencing here
}
```

It would just be slightly more convenient to work with references to the list's contents' values than with pointers to them.

Comment: You can probably write and adaptor but I doubt that would worse the effort

Comment: you may also take a look at the [boost pointer container library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) ...

Comment: Out of curiosity. What's so bad about `item->member`?

Comment: `It would just be slightly more convenient to work with references to the list's contents' values than with pointers to them.` to be pedantic, technically the pointers are the values of the lists contents.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think OP did not formulate question properly. It could be usefull when container holds pointers to functors for example. So you do not have to write `(*pitem)();`

Comment: @Slava - You mean function like objects, I presume? A bare function pointer doesn't require that.

Comment: @StoryTeller did I not say "functor"? I think in C++ that means function objects, but I could be wrong

Comment: @Slava - Could have sworn it was "functions". NVM

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot. But why would you?

```
for (auto pitem : list)
{
    auto& item = *pitem;
    item.member = something;   // no dereferencing here
}
```

Unless you're willing to write tedious code like:

```
template<class TPointer>
class Adaptor
{
    struct Iterator
    {
        TPointer* _p;
        Iterator(TPointer* p) : _p(p) {}

        typename std::remove_pointer<TPointer>::type& operator*() { return **_p; }
        Iterator& operator++() { ++_p; return *this; }
        friend Iterator operator+(const Iterator& lhs, size_t s) { return lhs._p + s; }
        friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs) { return lhs._p != rhs._p; }
    };

    std::vector<TPointer>& _v;
public:
    Adaptor(std::vector<TPointer>& v) : _v(v) {}
    Iterator begin() { return &_v[0]; }
    Iterator end()   { return begin() + _v.size(); }
};
```

Only then could you write:

```
struct SomeData { int n; } s1{2}, s2{4};
std::vector<SomeData*> data{&s1, &s2};

for (auto& item : Adaptor{data}) {
    std::cout << item.n << "\n";
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4313ad162d68aad0)

Comment: @slava Well, not with the provided syntactic sugar that for-range loop are. you'll need to write your own iterator, or an adapter of standard iterators. But, yeah, "cannot" is not 100% right.

Comment: "cannot" may not be 100% true, but "cannot without a lot more code than this" sure is.

Comment: If there's a simple language feature to do exactly what I'm trying to do I'd much rather know about it and make use of it than ignore it and write something longer. If there isn't then that's not a huge loss. Your version is perfectly adequate.

Comment: @YSC right, so please change your phrasing (you can but effect would not worse the effort or something like that)

Comment: The issue is more with the wording of the question. 'Something like this' is subjective and depending on interpretation of the question, the current wording of the answer can be 100% correct or less.

Comment: @YSC why what, sorry?

Comment: @Slava why did I spent the time to write that piece of code I'm clearly not proud of... Sorry the question was more intended to me than you.

Comment: @YSC I definetly did not ask for that, all I wanted just woring "yes it is possible, but do not do it"

Comment: @Slava yeah I know! Sometimes I'm so obsessed with useless things... This is on me, not on you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Boost has a range adaptor for this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indirected.html

```
for (auto& item : list | boost::adaptors::indirected) {
    // do whatever with your reference
}
```

---

Another alternative is iterator adaptors which are more verbose for this case: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html

```
auto beg = boost::make_indirect_iterator(std::begin(list));
auto end = boost::make_indirect_iterator(std::end(list));
for (auto& item : boost::make_iterator_range(beg, end)) {
    // do whatever with your reference
}
```

Comment: Is there anything boost doesn't have a solution for?

Answer (score 4):

Another variant using nested lambdas.

```
std::for_each(std::begin(list), std::end(list), [] (auto p) {[item = *p] {
    item.member = something;
}();});
```

Comment: @Snps the previous standard to be exact. C++17 was published in December.